# dataset Draw Chart with JFreeChart and MySQL DB

Tags: java, mysql, jfreechart

I'm trying  to draw a chart using JFreeChart on Java!

The data in which I'll use in chart comes from DB.

So I have a table of **pannes** with many types, I count then the number of pannes for each one and use  the method of JFreeChart to add them to the dataSet.

My problem is I didn't get any thing in output.

Here's the a bit of code!

```
for (int i =0 ; i<typesPannes.length ; i++)     
{
    ResultSet res = st.executeQuery(req+" and typeDerang = '"+typesPannes[i]+"'");  
    System.out.println(req+" and typeDerang = '"+typesPannes[i]+"'");
    int count=0; 
    while (res.next()) {    count++ ; }
    System.out.println(count) ;  
    dataset.setValue(count, " "  ,  typesPannes[i]); 
}       
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart ("BarChart using JFreeChart","row", "col", dataset, 
    PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false,true, false);
    chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.yellow);
    chart.getTitle().setPaint(Color.blue); 
    CategoryPlot p = chart.getCategoryPlot(); 
    p.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.red); 
    ChartPanel ch1=new ChartPanel(chart);
    panel.add(ch1);
```

is there any problem with the dataSet or .... Help please!

**dataset.setValue(count, " "  ,  typesPannes[i]);**

Thanks for help !!!

Comment: On a side note, you might want to learn how the `COUNT(*)` SQL function works.

Comment: What do you mean by "I did not get any output?". Is there some exception? does the chart get displayed blank or some other problem? Please elaborate.

Comment: There's no errors! and seeing the console where I made some System.out.println of executed pannes queries and their count number, the pannel in which I want the chart still empty!!

Comment: look at these :  http://i.stack.imgur.com/Iw9BT.png
  http://i.stack.imgur.com/Wnk6g.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dataset.setValue(count, " "  ,  typesPannes[i]);
```

Try replacing by:

```
dataset.setValue(count, typesPannes[i], "");
```

As you have only one category but multiple series.

Edit after seeing the screenshot:
The chart comes up fine for me when I replace panel.add(ch1); with new JFrame containing the chart.
So you need to check whether the panel is already added to your main frame and whether it is not getting repainted etc. You can try resizing the main frame. You can also try to add a simple JLabel and check that it is displayed in your frame correctly before adding the chart.

Comment: I used ChartFrame ch1=new ChartFrame("chart", chart); ch1.setBounds(10, 10, 700, 500 ); ch1.setVisible(true); and I get the chart drew! :)))) Now I want to embed it in the panel!
Thanks for help :)))))